# In the CPPTools extension for VS Code, is /** really recursive?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, intellisense, include-path

I just opened a folder (based on [this setup](https://gitlab.arm.com/arm-reference-solutions/arm-reference-solutions-docs/-/tree/master/docs/infra/rdn2)) in VS Code (1.74) containing C code I would like to be handled by the CPPTools extension (1.13.8). Within the folder (`.../rd-infra/arm-tf`), there is an extensive amount of code in the tree. The default `includePath` for the folder/workspace includes `"${workspaceFolder}/**"`. However, the second `#include` in the source (`.../rd-infra/arm-tf/bl1/bl1_main.c`):

```
#include <platform_def.h>
```

shows squiggles and an error:

```
cannot open source file "platform_def.h"C/C++(1696)
```

I tried right-clicking on the include to "Go to definition," but this failed.

Doing a search of the tree, I find about 74 versions of this file:

```
~/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/arm-tf$ find . -name 'platform_def.h'
./plat/intel/soc/common/include/platform_def.h
./plat/st/stm32mp1/include/platform_def.h
./plat/hisilicon/poplar/include/platform_def.h
./plat/hisilicon/hikey960/include/platform_def.h
./plat/hisilicon/hikey/include/platform_def.h
./plat/mediatek/mt8186/include/platform_def.h
...
```

I thought this made the error all the more odd, as I would expect a redundancy issue with so many to choose from. That's not what the error says, but I went ahead and added the specific compiler to `.../rd-infra/arm-tf/.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` to see if that helped:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "${userHome}/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/tools/gcc/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and nothing changed.

So, it appears to me that the `${workspaceFolder}/**` is not being recursively searched.

Then I added the specific include directory for the version of the file that applies in my case:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/plat/arm/board/rdn2/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "${userHome}/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/tools/gcc/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And the squiggles disappeared. I right-clicked on the include to choose "Go to definition," which opened the `platform_def.h` header file, where there were includes with squiggles as well, showing the same error as before (1696).

So now I'm in the same boat with a new include line:

```
#include <lib/utils_def.h>
```

Searching for that file:

```
~/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/arm-tf$ find . -name 'utils_def.h'
./include/lib/utils_def.h
```

So it looks like `${workspaceFolder}/**` isn't even making it one level deep?

I also tried with the full path, both with and without using `${userHome}`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${userHome}/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/arm-tf/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "${userHome}/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/tools/gcc/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and it was back to unable to open `platform_def.h` (1696).

Am I misunderstanding the `/**` notation?

========= **Edit 1** =========

Dumping predefined variables:

```
userHome:        /home/rtillery
workspaceFolder: /home/rtillery/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/arm-tf
compiler path:   /home/rtillery/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/tools/gcc/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc
```

Verifying compiler path:

```
~/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/arm-tf$ ll /home/rtillery/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/tools/gcc/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 2 802 802 1213640 Feb  2  2022 /home/rtillery/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/tools/gcc/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc*
```

And possibly related to @n.m.'s comment, I do get the following error (twice):

```
[12/20/2022, 10:47:36 AM] Unable to resolve configuration with compilerPath "${userHome}/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/tools/gcc/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc".  Using "/usr/bin/gcc" instead.
```

On the other hand, I don't actually see what the compiler output has to do with CPPTools recursively searching a path provided. (Adding `compilerPath` above was just a stab in the dark and probably muddied the waters around this question.) Maybe someone can explain if they are?

========= **Edit 2** =========

Also, probably not related. In spite of the variable dump above (accomplished using the example at the bottom of [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)), the editor shows a different expansion of the `${userHome}` predefined variable, which includes the variable expansion and the variable name:

From `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
            "compilerPath": "${userHome}/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/tools/gcc/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc",
```

Error shown in the Problems tab, under the `c_cpp_properties.json` file:

```
Cannot find "/home/rtillery/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/arm-tf/${userHome}/Projects/ARMFVPs/FVP_RD_N2/rd-infra/tools/gcc/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc".
```

That's very strange.

Replacing the line with one based on the `${workspaceFolder}` instead:

```
            "compilerPath": "${workspaceFolder}/../tools/gcc/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc",
```

seems to work, as the error disappears.

========= **Edit 3** =========

Filed [a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/169757) for the other issue mentioned above.

Comment: You need to tell which configuration file you are editing. There are too many of them. Note, IntelliSense understands the /** notation but your compiler doesn't, so you will probably need to list the directories by hand anyway (in a different config file).

Comment: @n.m. The configuration file being edited is mentioned above (`.../rd-infra/arm-tf/.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`). It is the one in the folder at the top of one section of the source tree.

(I had a different issue that one of my CPUs maxed out to 100% for over 18 hours if I used the actual root of `.../rd-infra`, as I would have preferred. So, I had to break up the tree into sub-trees of different workspaces. That's why the path to the compiler is outside of that sub-tree/workspace.) And I don't see how this relates to the compiler. This issue is with VS Code & IntelliSense in CPPTools.

Comment: So it looks like you are doing it correctly. The same kind of setup works for me (only I place c_cpp_properties.json in the root of the workspace). It's probably just VSCode and its extensions being finicky and buggy.